# How do I pass a URL as Action Parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action that expects a string containing a path to a resource ie "/123/something.html"

I am trying to user HttpUtility.UrlEncode() to encode the parameter but then the slashes are encoded to contain '%' characters and this results in a 400 error from the server. How can work around this in ASP.NET MVC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you certainly can pass those characters in a URL but they just have to be passed in the query string  in **the part after the question mark**

Ex : http://localhost/servercrm/contacts/query?search=%25%20%25